# File not found in webview in android

Tags: android

I have placed my static web application in an asset folder. My static web application has a lot of folders with files and placed in asset folder. I am calling html from another html with sub folder. I am getting 'file not found'. Can anybody tell me what the problem is? I post my code below:

```
wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/Opana_Changes/html/_assets/asset_001/index.html","","html");

       try {
        InputStream is=getAssets().open("Opana_Changes/index.html");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null; 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            html=html+line;
        } 
        br.close(); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

          wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/Opana_Changes/",html,"text/html", "UTF-8",null);


        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Check this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555459/1382289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code if your html file is in assets folder means in assets there is Opana_Changes folder and in Opana_Changes you have your html file. It will work.

```
wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

wv..loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Opana_Changes/index.html");
```

Donot forget to vote if my response is helpful for you.

```
file:///android_asset gives you path upto assets folder.
```

Can you give the exact folder structure where your file is located

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: In classic Android gradle layout `assets` folder has to be placed inside `main` folder along with `java`, `res` and `AndroidManifest.xml`