# I want to display the contents of html file (with formatting) on TextView in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

This is the HTML file I want to display on the Textview :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlight/styles/default.css">
    <script src="highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>C Program to Calculate Area of Circle</h1>
<p class="test"><pre><code class="c">#include&lt;stdio.h&gt;

int main() {
   area = 3.14 * radius * radius;
   printf("\nArea of Circle : %f", area);
}
</code></pre></p>
<br>
<!--Output-->
<div><br>Enter the radius of Circle : 2.0<br>
Area of Circle : 6.14<br>&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It has external linking to some **.js** and **.css** files

I've stored it in assets folder.

```
htmlContentInStringFormat="";
String htmlFilename = "www/"+fileName;
AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();
InputStream in = mgr.open(htmlFilename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
htmlContentInStringFormat = StreamToString(in);
in.close();
```

I'm using **mTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContentInStringFormat))**, but it is displaying plain text. I want proper stylized text, as it is displayed when I open the **.html** file like this :

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4SmS.png)

Please help me.

Comment: use webview for that.

Comment: Currently I'm using WebView only, but it seems pretty slow to load on some devices. That's why I want to display it on TextView.

Answer (score 2):

`Html.fromHtml()` will let you view light weight `HTML` in a `TextView`:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContentInStringFormat));
```

If you want your JS and CSS to work with it, you will need to use a `WebView`. To load an `HTML` file from your assets into a `WebView` you may [refer this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555459/1468093).

Comment: I'm using that only, but I'm not getting the desired output. Please have a look at the image I posted with question, that's how i want the text to appear on the TextView, but It is not linking the external .js and .css files I used for styling my html.

Comment: If you want external JS and CSS to work with it, you will need to load it up in a `WebView`. `TextView` is not made to handle a full fledged web page.