# on button click load/display local html file from asset in android

Tags: android, html, loading, assets, local-files

I'm new to android programming, is there a way to load or display the html file form asset folder in android by using View.OnClickListener

let me rephrase my question:
Is it possible to write a code similar the below to call/load/display the local html file form asset folder when button is clicked

```
public class testing extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);
        Button butt4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secition2);

butt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "http://google.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i)
    }
});
```

Do let me know if i'm not clear enough..

Many thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: this example shows how to do it using a webview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549420/loading-html-file-to-webview-on-android-from-assets-folder-using-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Create a activity with webview

and pass the url in bundle extra on button click

`"file:///android_asset/test.html";`

get the url and load into webview

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```