# Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/error.html

Tags: android, webview

I have a custom error page to show in a Webview, that is stored in the default asset folder `C:\Users\User\StudioProjects\Appname\app\src\main\assets\error.html`

In the `onReceivedError` method of a `WebViewClient` I load the page like this `view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");`

It worked fine when I coded and tested it, however the weird thing is, I tested it again, the Webview showed this error
`The webpage at file:///android_asset/error.html could not be loaded because: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994555/4722232, it worked for the html, but I have a logo in it and having the same problem and in the log I'm getting

```
"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/logo.png", source: about:blank (0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why you are putting your `logo.png` in the assets folder?

Comment: @abstractArrow where should I put it then?

Comment: An image (drawable) file goes into `drawable-*` folder. I also check your uri and there was nothing wrong with it. make sure to put your HTML in asset that is located in `main` folder. You can right click on `app` then `new` and `folder` and `asset folder`  to put it in correct directory.

Comment: @abstractArrow yes I did that, and it also worked ok the first time I coded it

Comment: I will post an answer shortly that introduces two alternatives

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I have a similar issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Not really, I stopped displaying the error page for now. But I might try turning the html into string and get the resource using Html.fromHtml(getString(...)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the file from asset and load into WebView

```
val htmlFile = "file:///android_asset/file_name.extension" //e.g. index.html
webView.loadUrl(htmlFile)
```

**asset** folder must be inside `main`

2. Get the content of the file from the asset folder and then load into WebView

```
val inputStream = assets.open("file_name.extension")
val buffer = BufferedInputStream(inputStream)
val bytes = buffer.readBytes()
val content = String(bytes)
buffer.close()
webView.loadData(String(content), "text/html", "utf-8")
```

3. Read the file from `raw` folder

`res` -> `raw` -> `file_name.extension`

```
val inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.index)
val buffer = BufferedInputStream(inputStream)
val bytes = buffer.readBytes()
val content = String(bytes)
buffer.close()
webView.loadData(String(content), "text/html", "utf-8")
```

---

You can use Kotlin Extensions to streamline this process

```
assets.open("file_name.extension").bufferedReader().use { br ->
    webView.loadData(br.readText(), "text/html", "utf-8")
}
```

---

Make sure your file_name.extension be lowercase and only contain _ if they are in either `res` or `assets` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used the inputStream, the html file works now, but my image is still not getting displayed. I moved the image to `main\res\drawable`. Would the path to it then be `<img class="logo" src="/drawable/logo.png">` ?

Comment: @FiloménaPetržlénová Now I get it. you are using the image for HTML file and that's okay to put it inside the `assets` folder. put it back in `assets` folder and that exact location depends on `<img src=""/>` inside your HTML. so the `assets` folder is your root folder.

Comment: yes, I had it in the asset folder, but I still got the `Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/logo.png` error. In the html file it was like this `<img class="logo" src="logo.png">`

Comment: @FiloménaPetržlénová Share your HTML file if possible so I can test it locally.